# Cannot set up blueimp jquery upload server for Node using SMF on SmartOS

Tags: solaris, node.js, smartos, smf

I set up a [node blueimp jquery file upload server](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Setup) on a Joyent cloud SmartOS SmartMachine (nodejs 13.1.0) instance.

It works fine if I manually start it using the command ./node_modules/blueimp-file-upload-node/server.js.

However, if start it using SMF, the server is able to reply to GET and delivering the pics, but cannot accept POST and breaks. Below is the template manifest, client and server error logs. Any help on how I can create the manifest to allow to receive POST much appreciated.

#### Common error to all manifest at browser POST

```
Request URL:
http://sub1.mydomain.com:8888/node_modules/blueimp-file-upload-node/server.js
Request Headers CAUTION: Provisional headers are shown.
Accept:
application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Content-Type:
multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary4x1QBIUsPyFwN0xP
Origin:
http://sub1.mydomain.com
Referer:
http://sub1.mydomain.com
User-Agent:
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.19 Safari/537.36
 Request Payload
 ------WebKitFormBoundary4x1QBIUsPyFwN0xP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="send-message"

 ------WebKitFormBoundary4x1QBIUsPyFwN0xP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[]"; filename="84a0ff8ef9ba11e1afba1231380fc0f9_7.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundary4x1QBIUsPyFwN0xP--
```

The SMF manifests -only what I change after the first one for each case:

#### SMF manifest as root - no  /opt/local/bin/node at exec

```
<service_bundle type="manifest" name="kamkam">
<service name="site/kamkam-service" type="service" version="1">
<create_default_instance enabled="true"/>
<single_instance/>
<dependency name="network" grouping="require_all" restart_on="refresh" type="service">
<service_fmri value="svc:/milestone/network:default"/>
</dependency>
<dependency name="filesystem" grouping="require_all" restart_on="refresh" type="service">
<service_fmri value="svc:/system/filesystem/local"/>
</dependency>

<method_context working_directory="/home/projects/egoer/sub1.mydomain.com/node_modules/blueimp-file-upload-node">
<method_credential user="root"/>
<method_environment>
  <envvar name="PATH" value="/home/projects/egoer/sub1.mydomain.com/node_modules/blueimp-file-upload-node/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin"/>
  <envvar name="HOME" value="/home/projects/egoer/sub1.mydomain.com/node_modules/blueimp-file-upload-node"/>
  <envvar name="NODE_ENV" value="production"/>
</method_environment>
</method_context>

<exec_method
type="method"
name="start"
exec="/home/projects/egoer/sub1.mydomain.com/node_modules/blueimp-file-upload-node/server.js"
timeout_seconds="60"/>

<exec_method
type="method"
name="stop"
exec=":kill"
timeout_seconds="60"/>

<property_group name="startd" type="framework">
<propval name="duration" type="astring" value="child"/>
<propval name="ignore_error" type="astring" value="core,signal"/>
</property_group>

<property_group name="application" type="application">
</property_group>

<stability value="Evolving"
```

#### ERROR WITH ROOT USER NO /opt/local/bin/node at exec

```
/home/projects/egoer/sub1.mydomain.com/node_modules/blueimp-file-upload-    node/node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:28
  this.uploadDir = opts.uploadDir || os.tmpDir();
                                    ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'tmpDir'
at new IncomingForm (/home/projects/egoer/sub1.mydomain.com/node_modules/blueimp-file-upload- node/node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:28:41)
at [object Object].post (/home/projects/egoer/sub1.mydomain.com/node_modules/blueimp-file-upload-node/server.js:211:20)
at Server.<anonymous> (/home/projects/egoer/sub1.mydomain.com/node_modules/blueimp-file-upload-node/server.js:134:25)
at Server.emit (events.js:67:17)
at HTTPParser.onIncoming (http.js:1124:12)
at HTTPParser.onHeadersComplete (http.js:108:31)
at Socket.ondata (http.js:1019:22)
at Socket._onReadable (net.js:683:27)
at IOWatcher.onReadable [as callback] (net.js:177:10)
```

#### SMF manifest as admin- all file privileges

```
<method_credential user="admin" group="staff" privileges="basic,net_privaddr,file_chown,file_chown_self,file_dac_read,file_dac_search,file_dac_write,file_owner"/>

exec="/opt/local/bin/node /home/projects/egoer/sub1.mydomain.com/node_modules/blueimp-file-upload-node/server.js"
```

#### ERROR with admin all file privileges

```
events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: EACCES, open '/home/projects/egoer/sub1.mydomain.com/node_modules/blueimp-file-upload-node/tmp/09008ecbfafd1c3570eff7ae0ae52fa8'
[ Nov 25 15:41:29 Stopping because all processes in service exited. ]
```

#### SMF manifest as root using  /opt/local/bin/node at exec

```
<method_credential user="root"/>
exec="/opt/local/bin/node /home/projects/egoer/sub1.mydomain.com/node_modules/blueimp-file-upload-node/server.js"
```

#### ERROR WITH ROOT USER - using  /opt/local/bin/node at exec

```
events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
at errnoException (child_process.js:975:11)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:766:34)
 [ Nov 25 16:00:16 Stopping because all processes in service exited. ]
```